# Can't reference POST variable at parts of the code in PHP

Tags: php

I have a bizarre problem that I believe should have a very simple solution but, for the life of me, I can't seem to understand what's going on.

I'm grabbing a POST variable and I first check if it is posted and echo it. It is.

However, when I try to form a variable that is a full path to a filename, it doesn't recognize it and I obviously can't open the file... 
I do get a warning for an Undefined variable so that's where the issue is but I can't understand why I can check the value of that variable anywhere and it's properly set.

Here's the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['fid'])) {
    echo 'fid = ' . $_POST['fid'];   
}
```

I form a whole path (which I echo and it is fine) to the file I'd like to open:

```
$fnameonly = getfilename($_POST['fid']);
echo $fnameonly; //echos fine, getfilename() worked fine
$fname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/' . $_SESSION["username"] . "/" . $fnameonly;
echo $fname;  //also echos fine, $fname should be properly set
```

Now in looking at the resulting HTML, I get 2 warnings:

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: fid in C:\web\www\csv\translatebs.php on line <i>23</i>
```

This is refers to the following line from the code above:

```
$fnameonly = getfilename($_POST['fid']);
```

The second warning refers to simplexml not being able to open the file since the path is incomplete.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(C:/web/www/uploads/paulohgo/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\web\www\csv\translatebs.php on line <i>31</i>
```

I can echo $fnameonly just fine but the warning is there. 
When I try to open the file the value from $filenameonly is empty, so the I only get the path to a folder but miss the actual file name.

I don't get what I'm missing here... thanks for any help.

Comment: the undefined variable refers to another line. If the examples you gave are actually in the code then I guess it is `echo $fid;` in the first code part. You don't seem to set this variable anywhere. To know what is going on with your `simplexml` command we would need to see the code where it is used.

Comment: Sorry, I was attempting something else and left the old code in there. I've changed it to the correct code which gives the behavior I see here. I can print $_POST['fid'] just fine. I've also edited the post here.

Comment: can you please post the full code so i can try to debug locally?

Comment: The issue is the same, the notification tells you the code doesn't have a variable $fid to work with at a place where you are using it. You are referring to the wrong line. There is a difference between `undefined index` and `undefined variable`.